# How can a function accept any type that satisfies an interface?

Tags: typescript

Is there some way to create a function that accepts a common interface of two types?

Consider the following [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN5wFzJAVwFsAjaAXwFgAoasATwAcUAhZAXk2NwGcwpQA5gG4yyAGRpqtRigDC7TAh59BI8ZJqbqMfCARhgAexDJESBmFQAKHGgCUmasmRQIYfFBNxqlTWYgW1li4AEwANMhKyABE9EwAtNBQhlDRZHZAA):

```
interface A {a: number}

type B = {b: string;} & A

type C = {c: string;} & A


function acceptA(a: A) {
  return a
}

acceptA({a: 2, c: "type-error"})
```

Type error:

> Argument of type '{ a: number; c: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type 'A'.

The `acceptA` function doesn't accept an argument of type `C`. Is there some way to change `acceptA` to allow any type that satisfies the `A` interface?

Comment: You are running into [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) which is more of a linter rule than a type safety issue.  Are you *sure* you want to do this? The implementation of `acceptA` can't possibly access the `c` property, and because you're passing in an object literal, nothing else can access it either. Whoever calls `acceptA({a: 2, c: ""})` is probably doing it wrong; if they care about `c` they probably want to hold onto that object like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8o4dW).

Comment: Can you articulate the use case where it's a good thing for people to be creating object literals with properties that are immediately ignored everywhere?  There may well be such a use case, but it would be nice to hear of it.  Anyway, if you want to work around excess property checking on object literals, you could write [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPZ1JN), where you explicitly use an anything-goes index signature.  Or you could use generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlvDGW).

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. That is just wonderful. My use case is more aligned with your first example than my example (and I didn't realize the difference until you've explained it).

Comment: Okay, great; I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: You can loosen `A` by defining it as `interface A extends Record<string, any>` - I agree with the considerations from @jcalz though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) considers `{a: number, c: string}` to be [assignable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) to `{a: number}`.  So in principle, every value of type `C` should be acceptable as a value of type `A`.  Why, then, does the compiler complain when you pass `{a: 2, c: "type-error"}` to a function that accepts a value of type `A`?

The answer is that this is a feature known as [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).  When you use an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) like `{a: 2, c: "type-error"}` in a context that expects a type like `{a: number}`, where the object literal has more properties than the expected type knows about, the compiler warns you because you are probably throwing away information:

The `acceptA` function only knows that its input is of type `A`; so inside the implementation of `acceptA`, you can only really access the `a` property.  If there is an excess property like `c`, you can't reasonably do anything with it inside `acceptA`.  And anything returned by `acceptA` would have a type that also doesn't know about the `c` property.  So the `acceptA` function throws away all excess property information.  And because you passed in an object literal, there is no other reference to that object from which you could reasonably do anything with `c` *outside* of `acceptA`.  So the `c` property is essentially useless, both inside and outside of `acceptA`... you might as well not even put it in the object literal.

And that's what the warning is about.  It's not that the extra property is dangerous or anything; it's perfectly type safe to pass a `C` where an `A` is expected.  It's just that the compiler thinks you're probably doing something you don't mean to be doing.

If you save the object literal to a variable which knows about `c` and then pass the variable into `acceptA`, there's no error, because you can always grab the `c` property from the variable, even if `acceptA` can't do anything with it:

```
const obj = { a: 2, c: "okay" }
// const obj: {a: number, c: string}
acceptA(obj); // <-- no problem now
```

So before trying to work around this, you should be sure that you really want to.  Excess property checking isn't *always* desirable, but it's there for a reason and you should double check that the reason doesn't apply to you before proceeding.

---

If you decide that you really don't want to have `acceptA()` warn on object literals with excess properties, there are remedies.  One remedy is to have `acceptA` explicitly accept a value that is both an `A` and an "anything-goes" object type like `{[k: string]: any}`.  A type with string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) can have any property keys at all:

```
function acceptA(a: A & { [k: string]: any }) {
  a.c // any
  return a
}

acceptA({ a: 2, c: "okay" })
```

That works because the body of `acceptA` can now potentially access properties like `c`, since all property keys are expected now. There's essentially no such thing as an "excess property" with a string index signature.  So even though `c` will be invisible outside `acceptA`, it is now visible inside.

---

Or you could make `acceptA` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `a` argument which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `A`, like this:

```
function acceptA<T extends A>(a: T) {
  return a
}

acceptA({ a: 2, c: "okay" })
```

That works because the compiler is prepared to keep track of the type of the particular value passed in.  In the case above, `T` is inferred as `{a: number, c: string}`, and so the return type of the function is also `{a: number, c: string}`.  The body of `acceptA` can't do anything with `c` (because it doesn't know what `T` will be), but because the function is generic, it's still possible in general to be visible *outside* `acceptA`... you could save the result to a new variable and that variable would have a `c` property that the compiler might know about.

---

Note that neither workaround *guarantees* that type information will not be thrown away; it's just that string index signatures and generic functions make it less likely, and excess property checking no longer applies.  There are still lots of completely useless programs you could write that the compiler will not complain about.  Excess property checking is just one heuristic that apparently provides a net benefit (although I find that it is such a common source of confusion that sometimes I'm skeptical).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJICWwALhAE4BmCyAgnkiAFxLACuYARjUgC+RIiQoBPGMgBCSALwteHKBWrkA5gG4hSAGRJGI4kglSkAYXkt4y1Ru2C9BoyVCRYDJAGUQANwgA8rwAVhDwFHguJEi0XMDhpAD2wKzwiDAUjAAU7AYAlJHG0UjUEBRc1CkgotHChDUk8MkqSIkhVrisHABMADRINkgARIkA1iDiQ0INSAD0swPNEW3BHLi53Hw0-YMqasDqdcUI6ZlZK3na80gAPAC0d5yJSDDUbRgQYE8A7lF1NW5oHBEEgAJLAAAmEAAHl5SOpQOVSoVirF4hQklU0hAMtlcsx9J0ANqjWz7dQAXQ4IGA4iEBQIRWiIAAdPA5gsaeIZiRSkiqjN-kyTjizp1cn0BhwRuNJvSakLXOAgZ4AOIQYA0UjsxmouIJZKpU6MG4AFSQMKokKgBgAfDkOKaGTySmUKgKmYrmdjcVlxT0dtKxhMpoI8gqjIIgA)